# Redux Middleware executing action without next called

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have an app which uses an accessToken + refreshToken to consume an API.
I wanted to add a middleware to check the accessToken and refresh it if needed before running an API call.

The issue I'm facing is that my initial action is always dispatched even if I don't execute the next method.

Here is my Middleware :

```
const requestMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  const {user, accessToken} = loadStorage();
  const payload = jwtDecoder(accessToken.access_token);
  const refreshThreshold = (Date.now() + 1000) / 1000;
  if(accessToken.refresh_token && refreshThreshold > payload.exp){
    // Here we defined that we need to refresh the token
    userConnexion.refresh(user.uuid, accessToken.refresh_token)
        .then((accessToken) => {
            // Token updated we can now run the next action
            return next(action);
          }, (error) => {
              // Error on token refresh we throw an error
              return Promise.reject(error.response.data.message);
          });
}else{
    // AccessToken is still valid so we continue with the next action
    return next(action);
}
```

}

For example if I dispatch an action USER_UPDATE it calls the action even if I don't run send any next action.

I think I'm missing something about redux Middleware but I can't find out what it is.

I'm using redux-think to handle my async actions, and I think the issue is the way I'm using it but I can't find out how to handle it. 
Should I have to prevent the next action to being run automatically?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out how to fix my issue.
It seems that I need to apply my middleware before thunk middleware.